# ARM64 Assembly file not executed when Archiving

Tags: ios, xcode, assembly

I use an ARM64 assembly **.s** file in my app.

I set *Valid Architectures* in *Build Settings* in *Xcode* to **arm64** only.

When debugging directly on my iPhone 6, the assembly runs as expected.

However, when the app is **archived** and installed on my iPhone through TestFlight, assembly code is not executed.

What could be the reason for that?

**Solved:** Target -> Build Settings -> LLVM Code Generation -> Optimization Level -> None

Comment: How does your application even work without some of its code?  This question doesn't even make sense to me.  Anyway, post answers as answers, not edits to the question.  And was optimization-level = not the problem?  Or did disabling optimization *help*?  If you're using hand-written asm in one part of your project, disabling optimization doesn't sound like something you'd want to do, because unoptimized compiler output is *slow*.

Comment: "No optimization" level compiles the fastest and generates the most debuggable code. So, disabling the optimization helped, any other level caused the app to crash.

Comment: If your code only works without optimization, it's buggy.  You're going to want to fix that soon.  Maybe you're using inline asm with incorrect constraints or something.